# How to get a website out of iframe

Tags: iframe

First I'm sorry for my basic english

I need to know how to get my website out of an iframe

Here is the case

If someone came and put my website http://example.com

In an iframe in he is website , is there any possibility to automatically redirect  to my website

Thanks

Comment: And what have you done to solve this problem? At least give the index.php or index.asp file whichever language you have made your site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but in your site you need to put javascript for redirect
so when anyone place your site into that blog or site with iframe they will redirect as per your condtion in javascript.

Try this for redirecting parent page.

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com";
```

Comment: you are right , thank you but this works in the my website too
my website couldn't stop loading and i can't browser it

Comment: well thanks for you Niketan , i got the solution to be appear for everyone , here is the code
<script>if ( top !== self ) top.location.replace( self.location.href );// </script>